# Call Https SOAP webservice in OSB 11g or 12c Business

Tags: oracle, https, servicebus, osb

When I call a https Webserice in OSB, an "Internal Server Error" appears.
I have added PEM file to weblogic KeyStore, DemoTrust.jks, and did all the [steps](https://coderwall.com/p/mzbkpg/accessing-a-ssl-webservice-from-weblogic-server).

Here is reponse metadata in SBConsole Testing window:

```
<con:metadata   xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/test/config">
<tran:headers   xsi:type="http:HttpResponseHeaders" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<http:Content-Length>38612</http:Content-Length>
<http:Content-Type>text/html</http:Content-Type>
</tran:headers>
<tran:response-code     xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">1</tran:response-code>
<tran:response-message      xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">Internal Server Error</tran:response-message>
<tran:encoding      xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">iso-8859-1</tran:encoding>
<http:http-response-code    xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">500</http:http-response-code>
```

Comment: Turn on message tracing. Perhaps there's something egregiously wrong about your request.

Comment: Thanks, but how turn it on?

Comment: Search on Google.

Comment: Shouldn't I use any OWSM Policy Store?

Comment: If you have OWSM policy you need to apply, maybe, but OSB works fine sending data to a straight SSL service, assuming the cert chain can be verified.